# CS1061: 'ASP.station_pages_stationfield_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'resizeIframe'

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am calling simple JavaScript method, and don't know why this error occur

```
 <iframe height="100px;"  onload="resizeIframe(this)" runat="server" id="frameDayLeft"
                    scrolling="no" style="border: none; width: 250px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

and here is the detail error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.station_pages_stationfield_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'resizeIframe' and no extension method 'resizeIframe' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.station_pages_stationfield_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its due to `runat="server"` .

Its not finding function at client side [Javascript function], but its trying to find it at serverside [on .cs page].

Thats why error is comming.

Try out this thing in codebehind>>

```
frameDayLeft.Attributes.Add("onload", " resizeIframe(this)");
```

Do like This>>

```
<script runat="server">
    void contentFrame_onLoadServer(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            contentFrame.Attributes.Add("onLoad", "contentFrame_onLoadClient();");
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function contentFrame_onLoadClient() {
        resizeFrame(document.getElementById('<%=contentFrame.ClientID %>'));
    }
    function resizeFrame(element) {
        alert(element); // do your logic here
    }
</script>
<iframe 
    runat="server" 
    id='contentFrame' 
    name='contentFrame' 
    width="500" 
    onload="contentFrame_onLoadServer"
    />
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how i can call javscript method on onload event of iframe

Comment: frameDayLeft.Attributes.Add("onload", " resizeIframe(this)");